# Como escolher o maior valor de um array?

Tags: php, array

Estou tentando utilizar a função `max`, mas não consigo acertar.

```
// variáveis da diferença salarial 
$saldev[0] = $_POST ["Tdate5"];
$saldev[1] = $_POST ["Tdate9"];
$saldev[2] = $_POST ["Tdate13"];
$saldev[3] = $_POST ["Tdate17"];
$saldev[4] = $_POST ["Tdate21"];

$saldev2 = max($saldev);
```

*(Nota: O código acima funciona da forma como está. Devido a um [erro inexplicável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2680/erro-inexplic%C3%A1vel-descoberto-ap%C3%B3s-ter-a-quest%C3%A3o-solucionada) recebi algumas saídas erradas e criei a pergunta, e à partir de algumas dicas descobri que estava funcionando (ok, é confuso, mas o que importa é que está funcionando). A hipótese com `ksort`também funciona para o mesmo efeito, então escolhi ela como resolvido)*

Mas a saída do `var_dump` de `$saldev` após o envio do formulário com os campos preenchidos, é:

> array(5) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2680/erro-inexplic%C3%A1vel-descoberto-ap%C3%B3s-ter-a-quest%C3%A3o-solucionada)=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" }

E o de `$saldev2` é:

> string(0) ""

O HTML do *form* está dentro de uma grande tabela, vou incluir um dos campos `input` (todos são assim):

```
<label for="Cvpos5"></label>
<input type="text" id="Cvpos5" name="Tdate5" size="10" class="preco">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe uma função para ordenar um array pelas chaves em ordem decrescente - [**krsort**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.krsort.php)

Use `krsort` para ordenar o array de forma decrescente e basta usar current para recuperar o primeiro elemento, pois krsort mantém a correlação entre entre as chaves e os valores.

```
$saldev[] = 'Tdate5';
$saldev[] = 'Tdate9';
$saldev[] = 'Tdate13';
$saldev[] = 'Tdate17';
$saldev[] = 'Tdate21';

krsort($saldev);
echo current( $saldev );
```

<sub>**Output:**</sub>

```
Tdate21
```

Answer (score 4):

A função `max` espera receber um array de números, então faça assim:

```
$saldev[0] = (double) $_POST ["Tdate5"];
$saldev[1] = (double) $_POST ["Tdate9"];
$saldev[2] = (double) $_POST ["Tdate13"];
$saldev[3] = (double) $_POST ["Tdate17"];
$saldev[4] = (double) $_POST ["Tdate21"];

$saldev2 = max($saldev);
```

Answer (score 3):

Tem um espaço na sua linha, o colchete deveria "encostar" na variável:

```
$saldev[0] = $_POST["Tdate5"];
```

Além disso, certifique-se que o form contem `method="post"` ou ele enviará os dados por `GET`. Quando enviados por `GET` os valores ficam acessíveis via algo como `$_GET["Tdate5"]`, que além de ser menos recomendado na maioria dos casos não funcionaria nunca utilizando `$_POST`.

Exemplo:

```
<form method="post">
```

Se mesmo assim não funcionar, poste o form e as URLs utilizadas, mas pela minha experiência isso deve resolver..